# React Context Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've generated a project using `create-react-app`.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import AuthProvider from './AuthProvider';

ReactDOM.render(
  <AuthProvider>
    <App />
  </AuthProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

AuthProvider.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class AuthProvider extends Component {

  childContextTypes = {
    test: PropTypes.string
  };

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      test: "Hello World!"
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          AuthProvider test: {this.context.test} // NOT WORKING
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But calling `{this.context.test}` in `App.js` doesn't seem to work. I don't get an error either, so I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Answer (score 2):

It appears `App` is missing a `contextTypes` declaration.

> [If `contextTypes` is not defined, then `context` will be an empty object.](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#how-to-use-context)

Try

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

App.contextTypes = {
  test: PropTypes.string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define contextTypes for child in order to access it.

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#how-to-use-context):

> If `contextTypes` is not defined, then `context` will be an empty object.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          AuthProvider test: {this.context.test} 
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.contextTypes = {
   test: PropTypes.string
}
```

Comment: How do I avoid having to define contextTypes for the child components? A high order component?

Comment: [`Consuming Context with a HOC`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-context-with-a-hoc) @Tiwaz89